# Reproduce the process of conducting the Chi-square test using R

Tags: r, for-loop, categorical-data, chi-squared

I want to reproduce the process of conducting the Chi-square test using R (I'm not talking about using the chisq.test() function), so I need to reproduce the "Expected counts" table.
Take this example, I want to test for the independence between Gender & Study mode. You can reproduce the data using the code:

```
dat <- rbind(c(3, 27),
             c(33, 9))
rownames(dat) <- c("Studying", "Not-studying")
colnames(dat) <- c("Men", "Women")

##               Men Women
## Studying       3    27
## Not-studying  33     9
```

Now I want to create a new table represent the "Expected counts" of each cell assuming there's a relationship between Gender & Study-mode.
The expected counts for each Gender-Study mode combination are based on the row and column totals. We multiply the row total by the column total and then divide it by the grand total. This gives us the expected count for each cell in the table. For example, for the Men-Studying cell, we have:
36x30/72 = 15
And want to do the same calculation for all of the cells. So I try using for loops to recreate the calculation but this is not what I want. Can you please have a look at my code and help me out!

```
expected <- for(i in 1:2) {
  for(j in 1:2) {
    expected[i,j] <- (sum(dat[i,]*sum(dat[,j]))/sum(dat)
  }
}
```

Comment: assign `i <- 1` and step through your loop, you would need to iterate over `1:2` for both rows and columns. or you can just do `outer(rowSums(dat), colSums(dat)) / sum(dat)`

Comment: @rawr The `outer()` function is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much! This makes my life so much easier. But can you please be more detailed about assigning `i <- 1` , as I also want to give the for loop a shot.

Comment: if your loop doesn't work, walk through a couple iterations, it needs to be nested and look something like `ex <- dat; for (i in 1:2) for (j in 1:2) ex[i, j] <- (sum(dat[i, ]) * sum(dat[, j])) / sum(dat); ex`

Comment: @rawr I've just edited my code, which is at the bottom of my question, can you please have a look. I've tried using nested for loops but it returns an error `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`